# Flutter: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build with Provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I'm calling one of the `ChangeNotifier` functions from an `initState()` method and the `notifyListener()` call inside the function is throwing
`setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.` exception

```
void initState(){
 Provider.of<MessengerRepository>(context, listen: false).setUnreadCount(0);
 super.initState();
}
```

```
class MessengerRepository with ChangeNotifier {
  int unreadCount;
  void setUnreadCount(int value){
     unreadCount = value;
     notifyListeners();
}
```

I need to call the `notifyListener()` inside `setUnreadCount()` as I'm calling the `setUnreadCount()` function in multiple places during the execution. So can't remove the `notifyListener()` only inside `initState()`.

Using `provider` version 4.0.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cause for this issue as mentioned in the log message is that the function inside `initState()` is requesting a rebuild through `notifyListener()` (the same will happen if we use `setState()` as well) even before the first build is completed.

The solution is to add a `addPostFrameCallback` and execute the rebuilding function inside it so that it will execute only after the first building of the widget

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding
     .instance
     .addPostFrameCallback((_){ 
      Provider.of<MessengerRepository>(context, listen: false).setUnreadCount(0);
     }
    );
  }
```

Comment: The best answer for all related question in SO

Answer (score 0):

You can move `Provider.of<MessengerRepository>(context, listen: false).setUnreadCount(0);` from `intState`to `didChangeDependecies` then it'll be called only once page finishes build process.

Or by this way :(less elegant)

```
void setUnreadCount(int value, {bool shouldUpdate: true}){
     unreadCount = value;
   if(shouldUpdate)  notifyListeners();
```

Then

```
void initState(){
 Provider.of<MessengerRepository>(context, listen: false).setUnreadCount(0, shouldUpdate:false);
 super.initState();
}
```

When you call it in `initState`, if the build method finishes before all your variables are (re)assigned they'll not be updated until you call `setState` or `notifyListeners`

[Learn more  here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleTickerProviderStateMixin/didChangeDependencies.html)